# PowerShell Find Users from First/Last Name, Error not showing on special Character

Tags: powershell, active-directory, french, get-aduser

I have a list of EN/FR users that have special characters in them. I am trying to get their SamAccountName but the script doesn't work correctly:

```
Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; Remove-Module *; $error.Clear();
cls
$ErrorActionPreference = "STOP"
$names = Import-CSV 'C:\temp\input.csv' -Header Givenname,Surname -Delimiter ","
$CompleteReport=@()
ForEach ($Name in $Names)
{
    $FirstFilter = $Name.Givenname
    $SecondFilter = $Name.Surname
    Write-Host $Name.Givenname, $Name.Surname
    $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter { GivenName -like $FirstFilter -and Surname -like $SecondFilter}  | select enabled, GivenName,  Surname, samaccountname, UserPrincipalName
    $CompleteReport = $CompleteReport+$aduser
} 
$CompleteReport | Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is my input list is not clear and that causes the loop keep on going without showing me the error on the item causing the issue.
How can I catch the user name that is causing this error?

Comment: you're using `-like` but no wildcards, are you looking for an exact match between `GivenName` and `SurName` ?

Comment: Yes, the file contains two columns that has Firstname and Last name. some missing the last name or can't find the item in AD. I can't figure out how to capture those and skip the bad inputs so I can manually look at them later...

Comment: Please open your input csv file in notepad, copy the first 3 or 4 lines and paste that in your question as formatted text. It looks like your file has column names `Legal_First_Name` and `Legal_Last_Name` and because your code specifies different headers, the existing headers are seen as data. That can only fail then because nobody will have a first name 'Legal_First_Name' I think...

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible that the error comes from empty strings on either *GivenName* or *Surname* from your CSV, as for sorting that problem, there is no way around fixing the CSV itself, searching AD Users by **GivenName** or **Surname** only **will not bring accurate results**. The following should at least handle the missing data from your CSV and point out those users that couldn't be found so you can fix your CSV.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "STOP"
# -Delimiter ',' is already assumed
$names = Import-CSV 'C:\temp\input.csv' -Header Givenname, Surname 

$result = forEach($name in $names) {
    $givenname = if($name.GivenName) {
        '(givenName={0})' -f $name.Givenname
    }
    $surname = if($name.Surname) {
        '(surname={0})' -f $name.Surname
    }
    $aduser = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&${surname}${givenname})"
    if(-not $aduser) {
        Write-Warning "Can't find Name: $($name.Givenname) and Surname: $($name.Surname)"
        continue
    }
    $aduser
}

$result | Select-Object Enabled, GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName |
Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: it is erroring out:

```
WARNING: Can't find Name: Legal_First_Name and Surname: Legal_Last_Name
WARNING: Can't find Name: John Mike and Surname: Doe
```